# VSCodeに出てくるフォルダの状態がわかりません

Tags: vscode

PHPで基礎的なサイトを作っています。
テキストエディタはVSCodeでDockerで環境構築しています。

ブラウザで表示させる際はエクスプローラーのwebフォルダにあるindex.htmlを使っています。

require()やinclude()で_header.phpや_footer.php、あるいはfunctions.phpを読み込んでいます。
今右側に表示されているのは_header.phpです。

昨日特に何も考えずに、appフォルダ内にCSSフォルダを入れて_header.phpでCSSを読み込ませようと試みたのですが駄目でした。
今のように、webフォルダの方に移動してやると問題なく読み込めています。

学習教材を進めているのですが、_header.phpや_footer.php、あるいはfunction.phpは簡単に「ブラウザ」に表示させないようにappというフォルダにまとめています。

このappのフォルダはどういう状態なのでしょうか？
実際にエクスプローラーから実際のフォルダにアクセスをしてプロパティを見てみるとアクセス許可はフルコントール、読み書き、変更も全て可能となっています。

このappフォルダは普通のフォルダとは違うのですよね？
これは教材からダウンロードしたものです。
実際に自分で構築する場合、どうすればこのフォルダを作成することができますか？
ローカルのフォルダのアクセス権を操作すれば出来るものではないようです。

拙い説明ですが、赤色のアイコンになっているappフォルダはどのような役割、どのように設定して作成されているのかご存じの方いらっしゃいましたら教えて下さい。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: vscode]

index.php
[image: index.php]

Comment: VS Code に何かファイルアイコン系の拡張機能を入れてらっしゃいませんか？

Comment: index.phpはどのようなソースが書かれていますか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。今調べたら"Material Icon Theme."というのが入っています

Comment: ありがとうございます。index.phpの画像は本文最後に追加しました。

Comment: 結局のところその辺のフォルダ構成や用途は学習素材の中に説明があるのでは？ それから「特に何も考えずに...」と書いていますが、素材に従った学習を済ませていないか理解していないのに思い付きで何か別の作業を行っているように見えます。まずは進めているという「学習素材」の内容をきちんと済ませて理解するのを優先した方が良いと思われます。まあそれでもこんな記事が参考になるかもしれませんが。[CakePHP のフォルダ構造](https://book.cakephp.org/2/ja/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html) 例えば質問の`web`フォルダはこちらの記事で言う`webroot`フォルダのように見えます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> このappフォルダは普通のフォルダとは違うのですよね？

いいえ、普通のフォルダです。

> 今調べたら"Material Icon Theme."というのが入っています

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PKief.material-icon-theme

こちらの拡張機能によってアイコンが変わっているだけで、ファイルシステムとしては普通のフォルダです。たとえば work/app のフォルダは Folder icons の App のアイコンになっていますね。